# Outputting more numbers than 8-bit in Binary Numbers

Tags: java, binary

Trying to learn Java (free time) and stuck on why this is outputting more variables than I want. I would like for it to just print out 8-bit. I've tried putting in &255, but not doing anything to get rid of the trailing numbers.

Example: 
The sum is:0000111110

```
Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in); 
int arr[] = new int[10];
int i,m,n,sum,carry=0;

    System.out.print("Enter 8-bit signed binary number:");
            int n1 = sn.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter another binary number:");
            int n2 = sn.nextInt();

            for(i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                m=n1%10;
                n=n2%10;
                n1=n1/10;
                n2=n2/10;
                sum=m+n+carry;

                if(sum==1)
                {
                  arr[i]=1;
                  carry=0;
                }

            else    if(sum==2)
                {
                    arr[i]=0;
                    carry=1;
                }

            else    if(sum==3)
                {
                    arr[i]=1;
                    carry=1;
                }

                else{

                    arr[i]=m+n+carry&255;
                }

            }
            System.out.printf("The sum is:");
             for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i]);   
            }
             System.out.println("");
        }
```

Comment: What is the user supposed to enter as input, a "pseudo-binary number"? as in a number with only 0 and 1? Because you read the inputs with `nextInt()`.

Comment: Sorry! yes! its suppose to be just 0 or 1 only!

Comment: What's the exact problem? The program seems to work correctly. Do you want to get rid of the leading zeros and output only 8 digits?

Comment: Its printing out this:

Enter 8-bit signed binary number:00010000
Enter another binary number:00010000
The sum is:0000100000

I would like the sum to be at 8-bit, not the number that is represented.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get leading zeros, is because you are forcing the program to calculate 10 bits, and printing 10 bits (`int arr[] = new int[10]`). To avoid calculating/printing extra bits, you could change the condition of the for loop, and keep track of how many bits the sum has:

```
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int arr[] = new int[10];
    int m,n,sum,carry = 0, nBits = 0; //Declare nBits, number of bits the final sum has

    System.out.print("Enter 8-bit signed binary number:");
    int n1 = sn.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter another binary number:");
    int n2 = sn.nextInt();

    for(int i = arr.length-1 ; (n1|n2|carry) != 0 ; i--, nBits++) {
        m=n1%10;
        n=n2%10;
        n1=n1/10;
        n2=n2/10;
        sum=m+n+carry;

        if(sum==1) {
            arr[i]=1;
            carry=0;
        }

        else if(sum==2) {
            arr[i]=0;
            carry=1;
        }

        else if(sum==3) {
            arr[i]=1;
            carry=1;
        }

        else {
            arr[i]=m+n+carry&255;
        }

    }
    System.out.printf("The sum is:");
    for(int i = arr.length-nBits ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);   
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The condition was changed to `(n1|n2|carry) != 0`, in other words, while any of the three variables is not equal to zero, iterating `nBits` at each cycle.